# Automation in \https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to automate a script in https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com with live test but i am not able to locate the elements there , please help to get this

Comment: Can you please specify the code that you have tried, then we can help you.

Comment: What are you not able to identify... could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Find the code to login into https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com through Selenium 3.x, latest chrome driver & Google Chrome 58.x through valid credentials:

```
    driver.navigate().to("https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).sendKeys("your_email@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword")).sendKeys("your_password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Log In']")).click();
```

Let me know if this helps you.